# How can I display a div on hover of another element using only CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display the contents of my `extra_info` div when I hover over the image of the dog.

I have seen syntax like :

```
.circular:hover + div.extra_info {
  display:absolute;
}
```

However I cannot get it to work!
Here is my code so far:

```css
.circular {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 199 !important;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
.circular:hover {
  border: 2px solid #16D3AE;
}
.extra_info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src=http://officialhuskylovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Cute-dog-listening-to-music-1_1.jpg class="circular">
<div class="extra_info">
  <h3>A lovely doggy woggy</h3>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdj6Lbgo/)

Comment: You search javascript or css solution?

Comment: `display` should be like `block` not `absolute`, `absolute` is for `position`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Adjacent sibling selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` or in this case you can also use [`General sibling selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/pdj6Lbgo/4/)

```css
.circular {
  margin-top:50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:199 !important;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:2px solid #ffffff;
}
   
.circular:hover{
  border:2px solid #16D3AE;
}
  
.extra_info{
  display:none;
}

.circular:hover + .extra_info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src=http://officialhuskylovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Cute-dog-listening-to-music-1_1.jpg class="circular">

<div class="extra_info">
  <h3>A lovely doggy woggy</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: So I had it - but my element was not adjacent - and therefore it didnt work :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
div.extra_info{
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div.extra_info{
    display: block;
}
```

This will work for following.

```
<a>Content</a>
<div>Content display on hover</div>
```

`div` element can be build a child of the anchor.